# SQL Server database script with data top 1000

Tags: sql-server

I know how to generate a script of a database with data and schema using the SSMS "Generate Script" Tool .

My question: is there a way to do that but only generate max 1000 rows for each table using "Generate Script" option or other tool?

Comment: any details? lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Export and import data wizard, and while doing it choose the option to write query instead of the whole table. 
[image]

Within the query give the select top 1000 * from ;

Comment: It a good idea, but can you explain how to create a script with multiple tables or point me where it is explained. I tried this Select  top 10 * From [dbo].[Table1]
SELECT top 10  * from [dbo].[Table2]. But it only toke the firs table